# Importing logging module in cython fails due to attribute error

Tags: python, logging, cython, importerror

> I am running everything on bash on windows

Here's what I am doing.
I have a `model.py` file which I'm trying to optimize by using `cython`. I made a copy of this file and renamed the copy to `model.pyx`. I added a bunch of imports in this new pyx file. The new file looks somewhat like this:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install(pyimport=True)

import cython
cimport cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

import logging
import time

DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t
...
```

Now I compile this to a .so file using the standard `setup.py` method which gives me `model.so`. Now when I try to use this model in a new python script it gives me the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 419, in load_module
    return load_module(fullname, source_path, so_path=so_path, is_package=is_package)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 233, in load_module
    exec("raise exc, None, tb", {'exc': exc, 'tb': tb})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 216, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_dynamic(name, so_path)
  File "__init__.py", line 77, in init logging.__init__
ImportError: Building module logging failed: ["AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'co_filename'\n"]
```

I'm not sure where am I going wrong. I searched a lot on google but I couldn't find anyone facing same or similar error. Any help appreciated!

Comment: There's going to be problems if you have a `model.py` file and `model.pyx` the same directory. Rename or remove `model.py` from the directory and also, do not use pyximport in the `.pyx` file. pyximport is done in a Python file that imports a cython module. I suggest using a `setup.py` file anyway.

Comment: Hi I forgot to mention this in my question. I have renamed the `model.py` to `model_org.py` in the folder. But removing `pyximport` from cython file fixed the error somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use pyximport in the .pyx file. pyximport is used in a Python file that imports a cython module, see the [documentation of Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#pyximport).